How to create an instruction from an anchor program with rust client?
Hi I have a simple contract testing slots pasted below. I have a question is there a way I can create an instruction for check_slot that passes in the 2 arguments? I read that anchor-client in rust doesnt support idl.json.
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

// This is your program's public key and it will update
// automatically when you build the project.
declare_id!("");

#[program]
mod slot_checker {
    use super::*;
    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn check_slot(
        ctx: Context<Initialize>,
        current_passed_slot: u64,
        max_slot_difference: u64,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        let slot = Clock::get()?.slot;

        if current_passed_slot + max_slot_difference < slot {
            return err!(MyError::SlotPassed);
        }

        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize {}

#[error_code]
pub enum MyError {
    #[msg("Slot difference too great")]
    SlotPassed,
}

